# validation max-min pattern input

Tags: html

How do I put 2 words minimum and 2 words maximum in an input with a pattern?

<input  type="text" name="name";  pattern="()">

So this field should have 2 words mandatory and 2 words max

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. I think [doing a bare minimum amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input pattern="^\w+\s\w+$">
```

Comment: You are welcome. Just keep in mind that \w includes A-Za-a and "_". If you don't wanna have the underscore, use ([A-Za-z]+) instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if plain html allows you to do that, but with the help of javascript it can be done, here's a related answer:

[Set maximum number of words HTML textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144715/set-maximum-number-of-words-html-textbox)

To add minimum amount of words, just change the logic a little bit:

```
if(numWords > maxWords && numWords < minWords) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to put 2 words minimum and also 2 words maximum at the same time.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's just adding a little more logic.

Comment: You are welcome. Just keep in mind that \w includes A-Za-a and "_". If you don't wanna have the underscore, use ([A-Za-z]+) instead